# Синоним слова днище

Tags: выбор-слов

Хотелось бы знать синоним слова "днище" в 60-70х годах прошлого века. Имеется ввиду плохой человек. Спасибо

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "днище"?

Comment: Имеется ввиду плохой человек

Comment: **_Иметь в виду**_ https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=ввиду&mode=slovari&dicts[]=71

Comment: Плохой человек - низкий человек, человек с низкими помыслами, корыстный, завистливый и тп. Днище, если это сегодняшний сленг, то это не "плохой человек", а типа мелочь пузатая, глупый, неразумный. То есть это что-то из разряда игр доминирования, а не из разряда нравственно-моральной оценки человеческого поведения. Днищем может быть просто плохо одетый подросток, дурак, глупец, человек не умеющий что-то делать, например, человек плохо играет в какую-то командную игру - он днище, так как находится внизу рейтинга игроков. А топ, топер - это тот, кто наоборот всех обыгрывает.

Comment: Ну или человек который не может постоять за себя, то есть не в состоянии соревноваться на равных, а тянет на дно команду.

Comment: Извините, вопрос был не про это. В 60-70х годах такого сленга не было.